# Error to call a rest web service on spring : HTTP Status 406

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I new with spring framework and I'm trying to do a web service with rest over spring, then I've the following controller that return a  List of `Customer` object.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(RestURIConstants.SERVICES_ROUTE + "customer")
public class CustomerService 
{
    @RequestMapping(value="/getCustomers",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public  ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getCustomers()
    {
        System.out.println("calling get customers service");
        JpaGenericController<Customer> customerDao = new JpaGenericController<Customer>( Customer.class );
        List<Customer> customers = customerDao.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Customer>>(customers,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My class Customer is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCode", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.code = :code"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByAddress", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.address = :address"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByPhoneOne", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.phoneOne = :phoneOne"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByPhoneTwo", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.phoneTwo = :phoneTwo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCreditLimit", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.creditLimit = :creditLimit"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCurrentCredit", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.currentCredit = :currentCredit")})

public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "phoneOne")
    private String phoneOne;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "phoneTwo")
    private String phoneTwo;
    @Column(name = "creditLimit")
    private Short creditLimit;
    @Column(name = "currentCredit")
    private Short currentCredit;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneOne() {
        return phoneOne;
    }

    public void setPhoneOne(String phoneOne) {
        this.phoneOne = phoneOne;
    }

    public String getPhoneTwo() {
        return phoneTwo;
    }

    public void setPhoneTwo(String phoneTwo) {
        this.phoneTwo = phoneTwo;
    }

    public Short getCreditLimit() {
        return creditLimit;
    }

    public void setCreditLimit(Short creditLimit) {
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }

    public Short getCurrentCredit() {
        return currentCredit;
    }

    public void setCurrentCredit(Short currentCredit) {
        this.currentCredit = currentCredit;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (code != null ? code.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Customer)) {
            return false;
        }
        Customer other = (Customer) object;
        if ((this.code == null && other.code != null) || (this.code != null && !this.code.equals(other.code))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.dev.model.Customer[ code=" + code + " ]";
    }

}
```

I used jackson mapper

```
<!-- JACKSON Mapper-->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to acces to the web services I get the following mistake:

```
HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

I need to setup something in the applicationContext?

**Aplication Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <!--Scan all application except the controllers  -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gteam.dev" >
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>


    <bean id="jdbcPropertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="classpath:project.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManager"/>
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider">
            </bean>
        </property> 
    </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

**UPDATE**

I try to put the file type that produce the services, but not works

```java
    @RequestMapping(
            value="/getCustomers",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces={"application/json"}
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public  ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getCustomers()
    {
        System.out.println("calling get customers service");
        JpaGenericController<Customer> customerDao = new JpaGenericController<Customer>( Customer.class );
        List<Customer> customers = customerDao.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Customer>>(customers,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And the headers generated by firefox:

```java
http://localhost:9080/controller/services/test/getCustomers

GET /controller/services/test/getCustomers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1067
Date: Mon, 29 Dec 2014 23:09:15 GMT
```

Comment: can you post your applicationContext.xml?

Comment: could you paste here the HTTP headers sent by your HTTP client? Especially the "Accept" header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  to your spring xml to make spring resolve sensible defaults